# I HAZ A FIBO, RLY

Tags: fibonacci-sequence, lolcode

First LOLCODE program, run [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lolcode_online.php).  This program inputs a Fibonacci number from the user, then determines and prints whether the number is in the Fibonacci series.  What do you think?

```
HAI 1.2

    HOW IZ I GetNum

        VISIBLE "Entr yr numbr: "

        I HAS A WatzNum
        GIMMEH WatzNum

        FOUND YR WatzNum

    IF U SAY SO

    HOW IZ I ProovFibo YR Num

        I HAS A Fibo1 ITZ 1
        I HAS A Fibo2 ITZ 2

        IM IN YR Nums

            BOTH SAEM Num AN Fibo1, O RLY?
                YA RLY
                    VISIBLE "YEAH, FIBONACCI NUM!"
                    GTFO
                NO WAI
            OIC

            BOTH SAEM Num AN Fibo2, O RLY?
                YA RLY
                    VISIBLE "YEAH, FIBONACCI NUM!"
                    GTFO
                NO WAI
            OIC

            BOTH SAEM Fibo2 AN BIGGR OF Num AN Fibo2
            O RLY?
                YA RLY
                    DIFFRINT Num AN Fibo1, O RLY?
                        YA RLY
                            DIFFRINT Num AN Fibo2, O RLY?
                                YA RLY
                                    VISIBLE "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
                                    GTFO
                                NO WAI
                            OIC
                            GTFO
                        NO WAI
                    OIC
                NO WAI
            OIC

            Fibo1 R SUM OF Fibo1 AN Fibo2
            Fibo2 R SUM OF Fibo1 AN Fibo2

        IM OUTTA YR Nums

    IF U SAY SO

    I HAS A Num
    I HAS A MaxNum ITZ 50
    Num R I IZ GetNum MKAY
    Num IS NOW A NUMBR

    I IZ ProovFibo YR Num MKAY

KTHXBYE
```

Comment: Only here do we take LOLCODE seriously...

Comment: LOLCODE at its finest

Comment: @RubberDuck PPCG does too. :P

Comment: @Riker *CGCC now

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
BOTH SAEM Fibo2 AN BIGGR OF Num AN Fibo2
O RLY?
    YA RLY
        DIFFRINT Num AN Fibo1, O RLY?
            YA RLY
                DIFFRINT Num AN Fibo2, O RLY?
                    YA RLY
                        VISIBLE "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
                        GTFO
                    NO WAI
                OIC
                GTFO
            NO WAI
        OIC
    NO WAI
OIC
```

equals this pseudo code

```
if (Fibo2 >= max(Num, Fibo2))
{
    then
        if (Num != Fibo1) {
            then
                if (Num != Fibo2) {
                    then
                        print "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
                        break
                    else
                }
                break
            else
        }
    else
}
```

Basically, what you've made has some strange bits.

Let's clean it up.

```
if (Fibo2 >= max(Num, Fibo2))//weird check, replace with Fibo2 > Num instead
{
    then
        if (Num != Fibo1) {
            then
                if (Num != Fibo2) {
                    then
                        print "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
                        break
                    else//remove useless else
                }
                break
            else//remove useless else
        }
    else//remove useless else
}
```

```
if (Fibo2 > Num) {
then
    if (Num != Fibo1) { 
    then
        if (Num != Fibo2) { 
        then
            print "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
            break
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Huh. Well, we don't need a double break.

```
if (Fibo2 > Num) {
then
    if (Num != Fibo1) { 
    then
        if (Num != Fibo2) { 
        then
            print "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Well, neither of these two can be true, due to the way your algorithm works (you do a check for `Fibo1 == Num` and `Fibo2 == Num` to determine if it is a fibonacci number). Remove the unneeded checks.

```
if (Fibo2 > Num) {
then
    print "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
    break
}
```

And translate back to LOLCODE.

```
DIFFRINT Fibo2 AN SMALLR OF Fibo2 AN Num
O RLY?
YA RLY
    VISIBLE "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
    GTFO
OIC
```

Well, that simplified things!

### Indentation

I still don't like the indentation, though. Three lines for a single if statement?
Let's combine them:

```
DIFFRINT Fibo2 AN SMALLR OF Fibo2 AN Num
O RLY?, YA RLY
    VISIBLE "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
    GTFO
OIC
```

This is the minimum I'd do. Even shorter would be:

```
DIFFRINT Fibo2 AN SMALLR OF Fibo2 AN Num, O RLY?, YA RLY
    VISIBLE "BOO, IZ NO FIBONACCI NUM!"
    GTFO
OIC
```

But then we're basically having the brace-style argument again; Put them on a new line or on the next?

### LOLCODE internal workings

I confused myself a couple times during the writing of this answer.

For instance, you had a `BOTH SAEM Fibo2 AN BIGGR OF Num AN Fibo2` check, but this is what the spec says:

```
BOTH SAEM <x> AN BIGGR OF <x> AN <y>   BTW x >= y
BOTH SAEM <x> AN SMALLR OF <x> AN <y>  BTW x <= y
DIFFRINT <x> AN SMALLR OF <x> AN <y>   BTW x > y
DIFFRINT <x> AN BIGGR OF <x> AN <y>    BTW x < y
```

And you have `BOTH SAEM <x> AN BIGGR OF <y> AN <x>`. So what is your version going to do?

Well, if we split it into two statements...

```
BIGGR OF <x> AN <y>   BTW Math.max(x, y)
SMALLR OF <x> AN <y>  BTW Math.min(x, y)
I HAZ A RESULT ITZ BIGGR OF <x> AN <y>  BTW RESULT = Math.max(x, y)
BOTH SAEM <x> AN RESULT  BTW x = Math.max(x, y)
```

Apparently `DIFFRINT Fibo2 AN SMALLR OF Fibo2 AN Num` is what you need. It basically checks if "the smaller of Fibo2 and Num" is "Fibo2".

Answer (score 26):

#### Separation of concerns

I like that you extracted `ProovFibo`... but I find it's doing too many things: I would have expected a function that returns a Boolean (`Troof`), and does nothing else.. but your procedure is keeping that information all for itself, and takes the responsibility of *also* outputting the result.

#### Readability/naming

You are declaring a `Num` variable, and the `ProovFibo` procedure is taking a `Num` parameter... and the loop is named `Nums` - Sure, *naming loops* is (AFAIK) very LOLCODE-specific and *it's hard*, but I'd prefer to see it named `Sequence` or something; pluralizing the argument name just feels wrong, and the name of the global-scope argument being the same as the local-scope parameter makes it a bit confusing.

#### While

A LOLCODE loop that isn't `UPPIN YR {variable}` is essentially a *while* loop... but you should be only looping up to a certain `MaxNum`, right? ...but `MaxNum` is never used!

It looks like the first two conditions (`Num` vs. `Fibo1` and vs. `Fibo2`) could be combined into one.

#### Input Validation

The user input is never validated - what happens when user inputs `LOL`? Or `-200`? The script happily casts the input into a number - you're leaving it entirely up to the language implementation to determine what happens... and that's not pretty: the program simply crashes with a cast error.

Comment: The parameter should definitely be called `MebbeFibo` or similar

Comment: Oops, that `MaxNum` is from back when I restricted it to values below 50 and checked them manually.  That value is never used.